# How would I time this function

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time

I want to determine the run time of a Dynamic Programming algorithm I have for solving Knapsack problems in Python. I am aware of import timeit and time but am not sure how to implement them here. I'm not a very good programmer!

```py
def DPKP(v, s, C):
    # Applies the dynamic programming method to the knapsack problem where v are the
    # values of the n items, s are the sizes of the n items, and C is the capacity.
    n = len(v)
    V = [ [0 for cp in range(C+1)] for j in range (n)  ]
    X = [ [0 for cp in range(C+1)] for j in range (n)  ]

    for cp in range(C+1):
        if s[n-1] <= cp:
            V[n-1][cp] = v[n-1]
            X[n-1][cp] = 1

    for i in reversed(range(n-1)):
        for cp in range(C+1):
            if s[i] <= cp:
                if v[i] + V[i+1][cp-s[i]] > V[i+1][cp]:
                    V[i][cp] = v[i] + V[i+1][cp-s[i]]
                    X[i][cp] = 1
                else:
                    V[i][cp] = V[i+1][cp]
            else:
                V[i][cp] = V[i+1][cp]

    return V, X
```

Comment: "I am aware of import timeit and time but am not sure how to implement them here." Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

You can take the time before running your function and after running your function and calculate the difference, e.g.

```
import time

# get current time
old = time.time()
# run function
DPKP(...)
# print difference
print("Time elapsed in seconds:", time.time() - old)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line of code-

```
import time

#at the start of the code
time1 = time.time()

#at the end of the code
time2 = time.time()

print(time2- time1)
```

This will give you the running time in seconds

Answer (score 1):

The [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module requires a callable statement, but that's a bit tricky to understand when you're new to Python and are trying to pass arguments.

The simplest way I know of is to just wrap your function that requires arguments with another function like below.

```py
def function_test():
    DPKP([1,2,3], [1,2,3], 0)

print(timeit.timeit(function_test, limit=100))
```